# Unused import statement 'import discord'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Начал писать бота для discord и столкнулся с проблемой, что на команды он не реагирует, притом если делать всё через @ping бота всё работает. Искал в чём проблема но в документации discord.py и на форумах так и не нашёл ответ. Единственное, что в коде вызывает предупреждение это (Unused import statement 'import discord') Может это как-то влиять на работу отклика бота на команды ?

```
import random
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

config = {
    'token': 'token',
    'prefix': '%',
}



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'],)


#Начало команды. Бот отвечает, когда его пингуют.
ping_1 = 'пинг_1'
ping_2 = 'пинг_2'
ping_3 = 'пинг_3'
#Конец команды. Бот отвечает, когда его пингуют.

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send(random.choice([ping_1,ping_2,ping_3]))
#Конец команды. Бот отвечает, когда его пингуют.

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)



bot.run(config['token'])
```

Comment: `Unused import statement 'import discord'` буквально означает, что вы не используете модуль, который импортировали. По факту используется только `import random` и `from discrod.ext import commands`

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Благодарю, исправил.

Comment: @insolor То есть это не влияет на то что, команда не работает? Вы не знаете тогда причину почему, команда не работает? Я следовать документации discord - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html




@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

Comment: @ТимофейВолколуп неиспользуемые импорты никак не влияют на работоспособность вашей программы, можно это предупреждение игнорировать или просто удалить эти импорты. Ну и указанный в заголовке вопроса текст предупреждения никак не относится к вашей проблеме. Причина соответственно в чем-то другом, но это уже не ко мне вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в `on_message` строку:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

То есть так:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user in message.mentions:
        await message.channel.send(random.choice([ping_1,ping_2,ping_3]))

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Привет, с отправкой сообщение при пинге бота всё хорошо. У меня проблема возникает в создании команды test.

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg) 

У меня бот при запросе %test ничего не отвечает.

Comment: Потому что Ваш бот не может пройти дальше on_message. Вам НЕОБХОДИМО поставить строку `await bot.process_commands(message)`

Comment: Вставил `await bot.process_commands(message)` .Это не помогло (

Comment: Давайте свяжемся в discord? qrts#9999